# mssql connection via odic

Tags: odbc, mssql

i have an issue connecting an mssql database via odbc in ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I have installed unix odbc and mussel driver.

mssql driver is declared in odbcinst.ini :

statadmin@dsc-stat:~$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.1.0
UsageCount=1

My DSN named DW16 is in odbc.ini :

statadmin@dsc-stat:~$ cat /etc/odbc.ini
[DW16]
Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Servername=10.0.0.52
Port=1433

a direct connexion(without DSN) on the database works :

statadmin@dsc-stat:~$ sqlcmd -S dsc-bdd1.dscptl.loc -U statsql
Password:
1> select top 5 libdef from defaut
2> ;
3> GO

### libdef

DEFAUT PONCTUEL
SUREPAISSEUR
PLIS CASSES TISSAGE
FIL TIRANT
FIL 
(5 rows affected)

But using the DSN, I get an error :

statadmin@dsc-stat:~$ sqlcmd -D -S DW16 -U statsql
Password:
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AFA.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server                                                   . Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

I suppose firewall, tcp porter authentification issues aren't here as direct connexion works. I've tried with IP address as well as with server name with no difference.

hope someone here will have a good idea to help me.

Thomas

Comment: In your direct connection you use server name `dsc-bdd1.dscptl.loc` and on the DSN you have it defined as ip `10.0.0.52`, are you sure both resolve to the same appropiate host?

Comment: Yes, i actually tested with both ip and name.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer, I don't know where my colleague found the answer, but here what he send me:

> [MSSQLTest]  Driver = ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server  Server =
>   [protocol:]server[,port]
>
> ## Note:
>
> ## Port is not a valid keyword in the ~/.odbc.ini file
>
> ## for the Microsoft ODBC driver on Linux
>
> ## You can optionally specify the protocol and port to connect to the server.
>
> For example, Server = tcp:servername,12345.
>
> To connect to a named instance on a static port, use Server =
>   servername,port_number. Connecting to a dynamic port is not supported.

my odbc.ini , needs to be:

```
[DW16] 
Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server 
Server=TCP:dsc-bdd1.dscptl.loc,1433
```

It works also with IP address.
Hope it can help someone else.

Thomas